# Python script progress email

Tags: python, email, progress

I have a Python script that loops through a list of 8 different machines and does a copy, execute, and test. I would like to receive an email after each loop. **I'm not sure what to google for this. I would appreciate any ideas that will help me with my task.

I am aware of the smtplib module, just not how to perform a certain task with it.

I did indeed check the handy search engine and found no previous questions that provided answers

**Question: how would one break in the middle of a loop, send an email, then continue with the loop??????**

I have an email when the script starts and an email when the script ends. I just want to be notified as the script progresses or if it fails.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you search "send an email from Python"?

Comment: This truly a Google question...

Comment: This truly is no question at all. I don't see a `?`, nor any request whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Python's [smtp library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html).

The example from the documentation is this:

```
import smtplib

def prompt(prompt):
    return raw_input(prompt).strip()

fromaddr = prompt("From: ")
toaddrs  = prompt("To: ").split()
print "Enter message, end with ^D (Unix) or ^Z (Windows):"

# Add the From: and To: headers at the start!
msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n"
       % (fromaddr, ", ".join(toaddrs)))
while 1:
    try:
        line = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not line:
        break
    msg = msg + line

print "Message length is " + repr(len(msg))

server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) package to create your message if there's anything nonstandard you need to do with MIMEtypes/etc. Use the built-in [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib) package to send it (and create it if you don't have to do anything fancy).

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance.